# Liquibase Insert computed value with multiple ids

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to insert values into a database. I think the SQL would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tb_config` (`name`, `value`, `description`, `unity_id`)
(SELECT 'new_rule', true, 'rule description', id FROM tb_unity );
```

However, I want to do it with Liquibase, using a changeset:

```
<changeSet author="Luis Sukys" id="1022" >
    <insert tableName="tb_config">
        <column name="name">new_rule</column>
        <column name="value">false</column>
        <column name="descricao">rule description</column>
        <column name="unidade_id" valueComputed="SELECT id FROM tb_unity" />
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

I've seen the use of valueComputed but with a where clause. 
The idea is that it includes one row in tb_config for each id in tb_unity.
I am actually getting a 'ValidationFailedException' from liquibase.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I use Navicat with MySQL and when I run this code, it includes one new row int tb_config for each row in tb_unity. The field i use from tb_unity is 'id'. 
If I have 05 unities in tb_unity, it must add 05 rows in tb_config, with same values, only change the unity's id.

Comment: You should edit your question and not write further details about your question in an answer...

Answer (score -1):

If you try running that SQL using whatever SQL tool you use, you will see that the problem is that you do indeed need a where clause. Which row of `tb_unity` do you want to use the id from?